# PHP - Filtering elements into a separate multidimensional array attached to previous key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I may be going about this in the complete wrong way, but I thought i'd first pose the question here. I have a log file generated from the Windows processes RoboCopy), which I have then opened up through PHP and created an array for every line of the log. I've then filtered through the array to only pull out the lines I need:

```
[0] => Started : 25 June 2015 13:12:48
[1] => 2015/06/25 13:13:46 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Getting File System Type of Destination \\test-lap\e$\test\
[2] => 2015/06/25 13:13:46 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Destination Directory \\test-lap\e$\test\
[3] => modified        4.7 m    2015-Map.pdf
[4] => modified        2.6 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PCL6_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154780.exe
[5] => modified        2.6 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PCL_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154696.exe
[6] => modified        2.7 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PS_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154863.exe
[7] => modified       45.7 m    V22.01.07.zip
[8] => modified       14.8 m    Chipset_Driver_H1VVY_WN_6.2.8400.39034_A03.EXE
[9] => modified       21.3 m    Chipset_Driver_M6X6G_WN_3.0.0.16_A00.EXE
[10] => modified            1100    cpaddin_example.ini
[11] => modified            1391    ddict.txt
[12] => modified           1.2 m    desktop.jpg
[13] => modified           5.0 m    EPS_uninstall_tool.exe
[14] => modified          741819    Install.log
[15] => modified          15.0 m    Network_Driver_64ND2_WN_7.80.218.2014_A00.EXE
[16] => modified            8746    New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
[17] => modified               0    New Microsoft Visio Drawing.vsd
[18] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document (2).docx
[19] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document (3).docx
[20] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document.docx
[21] => modified               0    New Text Document.txt
[22] => modified           1.8 m    OkiC5x50_ES2x32a4PCLx64GB_tcm3-37365.exe
[23] => modified           1.8 m    OkiC5x50_ES2x32a4PCLx86GB_tcm3-37451.exe
[24] => Newer              9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[25] => 0.0%
[26] => 2015/06/25 13:18:22 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[27] => Newer              9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[28] => 2015/06/25 13:22:00 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[29] => Newer              9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[30] => 0.0%
[31] => 10.1%
[32] => 20.3%
[33] => 30.5%
[34] => 40.6%
[35] => 50.8%
[36] => 61.0%
[37] => 71.1%
[38] => 81.3%
[39] => 91.5%
[40] => 100%
[41] => 100%
[42] => 100%
[43] => New File           1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:37 -> 13:41
[44] => 0%
[45] => 2015/06/25 13:45:17 ERROR 121 (0x00000079) Copying File c:\test\PSTools.zip
[46] => New File           1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:45 -> 13:50
[47] => 0%
[48] => 15%
[49] => 31%
[50] => 46%
[51] => 62%
[52] => 77%
[53] => 93%
[54] => 99%
[55] => 99%
[56] => 100%
```

What I'm attempting to do from here is whenever a percentage is shown, I want to unset the element and attach it to the previous element as a seperate array. So I would end up with something like this for each file reported:

```
[0] => Started : 25 June 2015 13:12:48
[1] => 2015/06/25 13:13:46 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Getting File System Type of Destination \\test-laptop\e$\test\
[2] => 2015/06/25 13:13:46 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Destination Directory \\test-laptop\e$\test\
[3] => modified        4.7 m    2015-Map.pdf
[4] => modified        2.6 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PCL6_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154780.exe
[5] => modified        2.6 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PCL_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154696.exe
[6] => modified        2.7 m    B7x0_ES71x0_PS_x86_ENU_2201_tcm3-154863.exe
[7] => modified       45.7 m    V22.01.07.zip
[8] => modified       14.8 m    Chipset_Driver_H1VVY_WN_6.2.8400.39034_A03.EXE
[9] => modified       21.3 m    Chipset_Driver_M6X6G_WN_3.0.0.16_A00.EXE
[10] => modified            1100    cpaddin_example.ini
[11] => modified            1391    ddict.txt
[12] => modified           1.2 m    desktop.jpg
[13] => modified           5.0 m    EPS_uninstall_tool.exe
[14] => modified          741819    Install.log
[15] => modified          15.0 m    Network_Driver_64ND2_WN_7.80.218.2014_A00.EXE
[16] => modified            8746    New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
[17] => modified               0    New Microsoft Visio Drawing.vsd
[18] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document (2).docx
[19] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document (3).docx
[20] => modified               0    New Microsoft Word Document.docx
[21] => modified               0    New Text Document.txt
[22] => modified           1.8 m    OkiC5x50_ES2x32a4PCLx64GB_tcm3-37365.exe
[23] => modified           1.8 m    OkiC5x50_ES2x32a4PCLx86GB_tcm3-37451.exe
[24] => Array
    [0] Newer              9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
    [1] => 0.0%
[25] => 2015/06/25 13:18:22 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[26] => Newer              9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[27] => 2015/06/25 13:22:00 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
[28] => Array
    [0] => Newer               9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
    [1] => 0.0%
    [2] => 10.1%
    [3] => 20.3%
    [4] => 30.5%
    [5] => 40.6%
    [6] => 50.8%
    [7] => 61.0%
    [8] => 71.1%
    [9] => 81.3%
    [10] => 91.5%
    [11] => 100%
    [12] => 100%
    [13] => 100%
[29] => Array
    [0] New File           1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:37 -> 13:41
    [1] => 0.0%
[30] => 2015/06/25 13:45:17 ERROR 121 (0x00000079) Copying File c:\test\PSTools.zip
[31] => Array
    [0] => New File            1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:45 -> 13:50
    [1] => 0.0%
    [2] => 15%
    [3] => 31%
    [4] => 46%
    [5] => 62%
    [6] => 77%
    [7] => 93%
    [8] => 99%
    [9] => 99%
    [10] => 100%
```

Of course if there is more than one percentage, I'd like to get it pushed onto the end on the new array, so it has a history of it's progression. This then moves onto the next file in the log.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on the best way to achieve this? If it's even possible?

edit: I should add that I already have a function that will give me the array keys that include % in it's value which will return a boolean yes or no. It's the moving of the data that I can't wrap my head around.

edit2: I realised that the child arrays would make little sense without the filename going with them. So I have amended my desired output.

Comment: Yes of course its possible. Warning: beware of removing Occ from an array you are processing over with foreach. Use a copy of the array to make amendments to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution, which generates an array that I can work with. To at least fill in those that maybe looking for something similar I used the code below:

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0){
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$modlog = array();
$addlog = array();
$x = 0;
reset($log);
while($x < count($log)){
    if(strposa(current($log), array("modified", "Newer", "New File")) !== false){
        $addlog["file"] = current($log);

        $x++;
        next($log);

        while(strposa(current($log), array("%", "ERROR")) !== false){
            $addlog[] = current($log);

            $x++;
            next($log);
        }

        $modlog[] = $addlog;
        unset($addlog); 
    }else{
        $modlog[] = current($log);
        $x++;
        next($log);
    }
}
```

This gave me the sample output of:

```
[24] => Array
    (
        [file] => Newer                9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
        [0] => 0.0%
        [1] => 2015/06/25 13:18:22 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [file] => Newer                9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
        [0] => 2015/06/25 13:22:00 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Copying File c:\test\OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [file] => Newer                9.8 m    OKW3E04V101_tcm3-155664.exe
        [0] => 0.0%
        [1] => 10.1%
        [2] => 20.3%
        [3] => 30.5%
        [4] => 40.6%
        [5] => 50.8%
        [6] => 61.0%
        [7] => 71.1%
        [8] => 81.3%
        [9] => 91.5%
        [10] => 100%
        [11] => 100%
        [12] => 100%
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [file] => New File             1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:37 -> 13:41
        [0] => 0%
        [1] => 2015/06/25 13:45:17 ERROR 121 (0x00000079) Copying File c:\test\PSTools.zip
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [file] => New File             1.6 m    PSTools.zip 13:45 -> 13:50
        [0] => 0%
        [1] => 15%
        [2] => 31%
        [3] => 46%
        [4] => 62%
        [5] => 77%
        [6] => 93%
        [7] => 99%
        [8] => 99%
        [9] => 100%
    )
```

There could be a nicer solution out there, but it seems to work for me. If anyone has any pointers then please let me know.